# How do I create a Boolean matrix with a corresponding index condition in Python?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, vectorization

I'm totally newbie in Python and i'm trying to create a 1280x720 BOOLEAN matrix which is TRUE when x-index and y-index are satisfied in conditions. Specifically, the black area is where i want all values is TRUE, others is FALSE.
[This is the image geometry of the matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFPnL.png)
So far i did a code like this:

```
mask_mat = np.zeros((1280,720),np.bool)
for i in range(640,1220):
    for j in range(0,360):
        if ((j > (-9/16*i + 690))&(j < (-9/16*i + 750))):
            mask_mat[i][j] = True;
```

But the loop take up so much time. So please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the range arrays based on the iterator limits using [`NumPy's powerful broadcasting feature`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and then directly use the formula, like so -

```
mask_mat = np.zeros((1280,720),np.bool)           
I = np.arange(640,1220)[:,None]
J = np.arange(0,360)
mask_mat[640:1220,0:360] = ((J > (-9/16*I + 690))&(J < (-9/16*I + 750)))
```

Take special note of the step : `I = np.arange(640,1220)[:,None]`. We are adding a new axis there, which represents the first axis in the output. This brings in the broadcasting feature to perform elementwise additions in a vectorized manner. The other range array `J` goes along the second axis of the output.

To further boost the performance, we might want to compute `-9/16*I` and re-use it in the two places of the formula.

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
# Original loopy soln
def loopy_app():
    mask_mat = np.zeros((1280,720),np.bool)
    for i in range(640,1220):
        for j in range(0,360):
            if ((j > (-9/16*i + 690))&(j < (-9/16*i + 750))):
                mask_mat[i][j] = True;
    return mask_mat

# @donkopotamus's soln
def fromfunc_app():
    return np.fromfunction(
        lambda i, j: ((640 <= i) & (i < 1220) &
                     (j < 360) & 
                     (j > (-9/16 * i + 690)) & 
                     (j < (-9/16*i + 750))), (1280, 720))

# Proposed in this post                     
def vectorized_app():
    mask_mat = np.zeros((1280,720),np.bool)           
    I = np.arange(640,1220)[:,None]
    J = np.arange(0,360)
    mask_mat[640:1220,0:360] = ((J > (-9/16*I + 690))&(J < (-9/16*I + 750)))
    return mask_mat
```

Timings -

```
In [86]: %timeit loopy_app()
10 loops, best of 3: 29.7 ms per loop

In [87]: %timeit fromfunc_app()
100 loops, best of 3: 11.9 ms per loop

In [88]: %timeit vectorized_app()
1000 loops, best of 3: 370 µs per loop

In [90]: 29700/370.0
Out[90]: 80.27027027027027
```

**`80x+`** speedup with the broadcasting based vectorized approach!

**Further boost with `numexpr`**

We could boost it further by bringing in [`numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/wiki/Numexpr-Users-Guide) to perform those arithmetic operations as one expression :

```
import numexpr as ne

def vectorized_expr_app():
    mask_mat = np.zeros((1280,720),np.bool)           
    I = np.arange(640,1220)[:,None]
    J = np.arange(0,360)
    vals = ne.evaluate('((J > (-9/16*I + 690))&(J < (-9/16*I + 750)))')
    mask_mat[640:1220,0:360] = vals
    return mask_mat
```

Timings :

```
In [101]: %timeit vectorized_expr_app()
1000 loops, best of 3: 321 µs per loop

In [102]: 29700/321.0
Out[102]: 92.5233644859813
```

**`90x+`** speedup now!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `np.fromfunction`:

```
np.fromfunction(
    lambda i, j: ((640 <= i) & (i < 1220) &
                 (j < 360) & 
                 (j > (-9/16 * i + 690)) & 
                 (j < (-9/16 * i + 750))), (1280, 720))
```

It may not be the fastest since we're evaluating a bunch of rows that are always `False`, but it may be quick enough for you (16ms on this particular machine)

**NOTE:**

As it uses matrix operations to evaluate the truthiness, rather than function calls, @Divakar's is much faster at 511µs